# MVC with Microsoft and Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio

I am curious about the strategies adopted by the two leading vendors on MVC.
Whereas microsoft has currently unvieled MVC 2 and Oracle seems to have Oracle ADF which is based on Java and JSF but provides darg and drop functionality .

Does this mean in the MVC race because of Oracle ADF drag and drop they are ahead of microsoft in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my experiences of the two technologies, probably doesn't answer your question directly but I thought I'd share it anyway:

I've recently ported an ADF application over to MVC. I found MVC easier to work with in general. ADF's declarative databinding and Faces page flow configuration is elegant, but I found it awkward to use at times. Conversely, I get the impression it would be easier to break rules and good practice within Microsoft's framework, but that's probably just me being ill-disciplined!

I was using Toplink with ADF which I migrated over to NHibernate fairly easily.

Regarding drag and drop in JDeveloper, I never really found myself using it. The rendering engine didn't seem fine-tuned enough to give an accurate representation of the final page and I found it generally clunky, so I stuck with the XML in the editor.

I'm still getting to grips with MVC, but hope this info is helpful anyway.

Comment: Richard thanks a million for responding but doesnt oracle claim that ADF si actually draga nd drop MVC ?

Comment: It's drag and drop in the sense that the visual designer allows you to create pages that way from a palette of components, and of course the JSF navigation diagram is drag and drop. I suppose the 'drag and drop MVC' you are referring to relates mainly to dragging data controls into the visual designer. It's a nice system that works well as all relevant component options are displayed depending on what elements or methods you drag.

Comment: Richard any idea whats the business motivation to convert from ADF to mvc

Comment: The main reason was to standardise our development environment within our team. The majority of our systems are ASP.NET based, we are now only using Java based systems where developments on Unix systems are required.